Extension refuses to load the script due to CSP violation
I'm an SE user often chatting in the physics and math chat rooms. Since yesterday, the chrome extension SE mathjax hasn't been able to render the mathjax formatted lines which I previously used to get displayed. To be totally straightforward, I do know anything about how these things work and after clicking on one of the $...$ mathjax lines in the chat, I inspected the element and found this two errors occurred which seem to me as the cause of the problem:


Now I searched what these messages stand for and see if I could find any solution on SO, but unfortunately, I can't even interpret the two answers to the two questions I found related to my problem. I kind of intuitively get being discussed but not what I can do to solve it.
Anyways, this is where the link in the second image gets me. It is probably the source code, which I obviously cannot interpret.
Could anybody guide me in how to solve this problem.
Thanks in advance
I could not try to do anything because I do not currently know the languages being used in the source code or in the answers I linked.
P.S. I think the problem might be in the following lines:
// Create a script object to add the MathJax configuration
var script = document.createElement("script");
script.src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/3.2.2/es5/tex-svg.js";

// Add MathJax to the page
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);


"Your site" in this context is the whatever stackexchange site that defines the CSP in question. So if you want to suggest that stackexchange should revise its policies, https://meta.stackexchange.com/ may be the place for that.

On the other hand, fixing a Chrome extension of someone else may not be very straightforward, it depends on availability of source code for example, and then you would have to run it locally in developer mode, as you can't fix the extension in the store, only on your PC. Which is not hard, but still is a bit of a quirk. It may be better to reach out to the developer, especially if you don't actually know JavaScript.

Asking for a possible fix/workaround from an end-user's perspective may be a question for https://superuser.com/

And whatever the error messages say, the issue may be related to Chrome phasing out support for older-style extensions in these days, https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/migrate/mv2-deprecation-timeline - yet again something that the maintainer of the extension has better chances to address.

thanks for the hints, I will do as you suggested
